# Facing issues with enabling navigation buttons & getting data in timeline chart using vis.js

Tags: vis.js, timeline.js

I created timeline chart using chaps link library and now moving to use vis.js . I am facing the following issues. appreciate any pointers in getting it addressed
1) In chaps link library there was option to show the navigation button, which i couldn't bring it on the chart using vis.js.

2)On selecting an item on the timeline chart how to get the data associated with the item.In chaps link library I was able to get the data using timeline.getData() method and from that i was able to get the data for the selection. Is there any api available which could get me the data of the selected item.

Comment: <Updated>
I am able to solve my second problem of getting data of the selected item using timeline.itemsData.get(properties.item).

Answer (score 0):

There are no navigation buttons available which can be shown by using the vis.js API. But you can create your own navigation buttons. You can use the timeline methods `moveTo(time [, options])` and `setWindow(start, end [, options])`.
The first one moves the timeline to a certain date, and the second one can be used to zoom in and out by setting the parameter accordingly.